# Flink Queryable State Error

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use queryable state on Flink (version 1.4.2) but unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

```
INFO  my.test.flink.QueryableState  - Params are a96438fa12879b7598c9cf32684e2669, kafka-cluster_jobmanager_1, 6123
INFO  my.test.flink.QueryableState  - Before the call java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@26aa12dd[Not completed]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        at my.test.flink.QueryableState.main(QueryableState.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(4) exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1166)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readInt(AbstractByteBuf.java:619)
        at org.apache.flink.queryablestate.network.messages.MessageSerializer.deserializeHeader(MessageSerializer.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.queryablestate.network.ClientHandler.channelRead(ClientHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On the client side I am using flink-queryable-state-client-java_2_11.jar and the relevant part of code for the  queryable client is

```
QueryableStateClient client = new QueryableStateClient(jobManagerHost, jobManagerPort);

TypeInformation<MyEvent> typeInformation = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<MyEvent>() {});
ListStateDescriptor<MyEvent> descriptor = new ListStateDescriptor<MyEvent>("myEvents",
                 typeInformation.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig()));

CompletableFuture<ListState<MyEvent>> resultFuture =
                        client.getKvState(JobID.fromHexString(jobIdParam),"myEvents", "1", 
                        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO , descriptor );

logger.info("Before the call " + resultFuture);
try {
         logger.info("Finished"+ resultFuture.get());
 } catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Finally the job running on Flink has a ListState configured as it can been seen below. Note that data are keyed on ListState by String

```
        TypeInformation<MyEvent> typeInformation = TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<MyEvent>() {});
        ListStateDescriptor<MyEvent> eventState = 
                new ListStateDescriptor<MyEvent>("myEvents",typeInformation);
        eventState.setQueryable("myEvents");
        eventListState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(eventState);
```

It seems to me like a serialization error but I do not know what I need to do to fix it. Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong with code above ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that exact same problem when updating [this queryable state demo](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-queryable_state_demo) for Flink 1.4. If I recall correctly, the important part is dealing with the CompletableFuture correctly -- you can't just call get() straightaway.

See [the code](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-queryable_state_demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/queryablestatedemo/EventCountClient.java#L72) for a working example, the key part of which looks something like this:

```
try {

    CompletableFuture<FoldingState<BumpEvent, Long>> resultFuture =
      client.getKvState(jobId, EventCountJob.ITEM_COUNTS, key, 
      BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, countingState);

    resultFuture.thenAccept(response -> {
      try {
        Long count = response.get();
        // now we could do something with the value
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    });

    resultFuture.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem was that I was under the impression that I should use RPC port on jobmanager instead of port 9069 which was the default query proxy port on taskmanager. Thanks though about the info on CompletableFuture there were also helpful for getting the final results.